# MacBook IR adaptor

Tags: macbook-pro, remote-control

I have a MacBook AIR without IR and an Apple remote control (bought without knowing my laptop didn't have IR). I am looking for an IR adaptor. Can you please recommend me one that works on Mac?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Mira](http://twistedmelon.com/mira/) and [Remote Buddy](http://www.iospirit.com/products/remotebuddy/), which are programs to enable the Apple Remote on systems that don't have it built-in (they also provide expanded functionality I believe). They both have hardware compatibility lists that should provide you with some good suggestions ([here](http://twistedmelon.com/mira/hardware.html) for Mira, and [here](http://www.iospirit.com/products/remotebuddy/hardware/) for Remote Buddy.

Comment: Thank you. I also found these:http://www.amazon.co.uk/Max-Value-Infrared-Adapter-MV42440/dp/B001GXR77E/ref=cm_srch_res_rtr_1 or http://www.amazon.com/Adapter-USB-2-0-IrDA-Compatible/dp/B006VJ049Q or http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B000JPGQ4U/ref=pd_lpo_k2_dp_sr_2?pf_rd_p=486540031&pf_rd_s=lpo-top-stripe-1&pf_rd_t=201&pf_rd_i=B006VJ049Q&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_r=10TK3KDCSWE3QJTTSJQD. The comments are pro and against. Do you think one of there might help me use the remote? Thank you!

Comment: I checked the site indicated: http://twistedmelon.com/mira/ It is yet unclear for me (I am not specialist at all): should I also order an external IR receiver or is it enough to buy the software? (I have the Apple remote). Thanks

Comment: You definitely need a receiver if you have a Mac without a built-in receiver. Otherwise the software has no way to read the IR signals.